# Magento1.9: Customer Account Information Edit Form Admin Dashboard

Tags: magento-1.9, template, debugging

[image: Where can i find the template form for this account information Tab]

**Where can i find the template form for this account information Tab magento 1.9?**

Answer (score 0):

The feature wasn't designed to be used on the admin. Its system config is explicitly set to only allow you to se this at the website or store level, not the global level.

Assuming this is just for work in a development environment, the approach I'd take would be to override the class

```
Mage_Core_Block_Template
```

and override (with a class alias override, or a local/Mage replacement) the getShowTemplateHints method hints.

```
public function getShowTemplateHints()
{
     //return false
     return true; 
}

//     old method, here for demo purposes only.  Don't hack the core
//     public function getShowTemplateHints()
//     {
//         if (is_null(self::$_showTemplateHints)) {
//             self::$_showTemplateHints = Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/debug/template_hints')
//                 && Mage::helper('core')->isDevAllowed();
//             self::$_showTemplateHintsBlocks = Mage::getStoreConfig('dev/debug/template_hints_blocks')
//                 && Mage::helper('core')->isDevAllowed();
//         }
//         return self::$_showTemplateHints;
//     }
```

You can then manually change getShowTemplateHints to return true or false if you want the feature on or off, or add whatever additional logic you wanted.

I would not recommend you push this change to the production server.
[image]

Comment: Yogesh, I have found the hints, but i need to know how the  attributes fields and labels are rendering in account Information Tab

Comment: Please create the new question with a specific point.